# How do I select from the tables listed in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, information-schema

The information schema has a view called tables that lists the names of all the tables in the database. If all the the tables the same columns and I'd want to select table_name, value of certain column, how would I do that?

For example, I have TABLES

| table_name | ... |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE1 | ... |
| TABLE2 | ... |
| TABLE3 | ... |

TABLE1

| common_column | val |
| --- | --- |
| this_value | A |
| not_this_value | B |
| not_this_value | C |

TABLE2

| common_column | val |
| --- | --- |
| not_this_value | A |
| this_value | B |
| not_this_value | C |

TABLE3

| common_column | val |
| --- | --- |
| not_this_value | A |
| not_this_value | B |
| this_value | C |

and I want an output of all the table_names with their value when common_column='this_value':

| table_name | val |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE1 | A |
| TABLE2 | B |
| TABLE3 | C |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use RESULT_SCAN to achieve this (See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan)

It is a bit unclear from your post what column you want to filter on.

Please try using the below queries and let me know if this helps:
(you have to first run a select query from the information_schema.tables view in order to use its result in RESULT_SCAN)

```
select * from information_schema.tables;
select table_name,
case 
    WHEN column1 = 1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN column1 = 2 THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'C'
END AS val
from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) where common_column='this_value';
```

Comment: I want to return the value in the 'val' column of the entry where common_column = 'this_value'

Answer (score 0):

use the COLUMNS table:

```
select 
    table_catalog, 
    table_schema, 
    table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'ID';
```

[image]